# SELECT value only once per date in CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, case

Subset of Table T, which is also the **Desired Output**, when ExtID = 24:

```
   CID     SDate     Cost
    1    9/9/2016     70
    1    9/14/2016     0
    1    9/16/2016    70
    2    9/9/2016      0
    2    9/14/2016    70
    2    9/16/2016     0
```

I want the Cost to be on a per-date basis i.e. say when ExtID=24, the Cost for any CID for a given date needs to be 70 but the remaining Costs should then be 0 for that given date. The amount can only be 70 once for a given date.

Query:

```
SELECT 
     CID
    ,SDate
    ,CASE WHEN ExtID = 24 THEN 70 END        
FROM Table T
```

This will obviously give me all costs as 70. How do I modify the `CASE` expression?

Comment: "ExtID" is referenced in your text and "EID" is used in your SQL script. Do they represent the same thing or something different?

Comment: Edited: ExtID in query

Comment: so you want the cost to be set as the first value seen for that date?

Comment: Not mandatory. But if that helps, sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one selects the minimum CID for each date, and assigns a cost of 70 to that record. For all other records with the same date but a higher CID, 0 is assigned as cost.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.cid, t.sdate,
CASE WHEN t.cid = sub.cidmin THEN 70
ELSE 0 END AS cost
FROM t
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT sdate, MIN(cid) as cidmin
FROM t
GROUP BY sdate) sub
ON t.cid = sub.cidmin
AND t.sdate = sub.sdate
```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72a221/11

Answer (score 0):

You could use a window function for this:

```
SELECT 
     CID
    ,SDate
    ,CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE ORDER BY CID ASCENDING ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) = 0 AND EID = 24 THEN 70 END        
FROM Table T
```

THis will cound how many of this date appear before this record when sorted by CID. If it's 0 then we are at the first record, so test your EID and stick 70 in there (can probably remove the test for EID now, but left it in in case it's needed).

Comment: Won't it be Ascending by default for `ORDER BY CID`? I'm getting 70's for all results still.

Comment: Yes, it will be. perhaps as a seperate column, use: `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE ORDER BY CID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)` and see what you get for a count. Then base your CASE on those results.

Comment: The count is 0 for each row which is why the costs are all 70's